# Integration of logarithms

Tags: calculus, integration

Integral of $$1\over x(log_4^x)^2$$.

I changed  $$(log_4^x)^2$$ 
to 
$$2(ln(4)/(ln(x))$$

Then I integrated and got 
$$.5ln(4)(ln(ln(x))$$
The answer to the problem is

$$ -ln(4)/(log_4^x) + C...$$
Can my solution be converted into the answer?

Is my method right?
If not, how is it wrong?

Comment: Isn't this your 93rd question? We use $\LaTeX$ here.

Comment: How do I write logarithms using mathjax?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: question was edited for mathjax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you meant
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{x\left(\log_4\left|x\right|\right)^2}?
\end{align}
It would be a good idea to pick up some of the LaTeX math commands in the near future if you're posting here because it makes life easier for the rest of us when trying to answer your questions -- so we know exactly what you mean, per say, and don't give you the "wrong" answer. If that is the case, then observe that usually the best thing to do with logs of an odd base (even base-10) in calculus is to split them up like $\log_a\left|x\right|=\frac{\log\left|x\right|}{\log\left|a\right|}$. That is what you will want to do here, only you cannot take the exponent down like you have (if I'm correct in my assumption above). Therefore, we may write that
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{x\left(\frac{\log\left|x\right|}{\log\left|4\right|}\right)^2}=\left(\log\left|4\right|\right)^2\int\frac{dx}{x\left(\log\left|x\right|\right)^2},\tag{1}
\end{align}
Now let $z=\log\left|x\right|$, which means that $x\:dz=dx$, leaving us with
\begin{align}
\left(\log\left|4\right|\right)^2\int\frac{dz}{z^2}=\frac{-\left(\log\left|4\right|\right)^2}{\log\left|x\right|}+C.\tag{2}
\end{align}

Comment: The x is not supposed to be in absolute value

Comment: @AmandaKelius I do that out of habit if we're strictly in the real domain, since logarithms are not defined in the real domain for odd numbers -- does the exponential $e^x$ ever pass below the $x$-axis?

Comment: Why did you not take the squared out in the first step of evaluating the integral? i.e. make the base 2x times the logarithm

Comment: @AmandaKelius It depends, as I couldn't decide whether you meant $\left(\log\left|x\right|\right)^2$ or $\log\left|x^2\right|$ -- I assumed the former because it looks an awful lot like what you wrote in your question above. Please write it better in LaTeX from now on so there is no more confusion, as I have indicated in my post.

Comment: To be clear: $\log(x^2)$ is equal to $2\log x$, but $(\log x)^2$ is not equal to $2\log x$.